# Building Kata Containers kernel with GPU Support; .config file build not working due to lack of variables?

Tags: kernel, docker, gpu, container, gpu-passthrough

I am trying to follow the instructions here (https://github.com/kata-containers/documentation/blob/master/use-cases/Nvidia-GPU-passthrough-and-Kata.md)  to build a Kata Containers kernel so I can enable GPU support on Kata Containers.

I am trying to use these commands to build the kernel:

```
./build-kernel.sh -v 4.19.86 -g nvidia -f setup 
./build-kernel.sh -v 4.19.86 -g nvidia build
sudo -E ./build-kernel.sh -v 4.19.86 -g nvidia install
```

However, the very first one (./build-kernel.sh -v 4.19.86 -g nvidia -f setup)  is giving me an error that I don't have a whole list of variables inside my config file:

```
INFO: Add kernel config for GPU due to '-g nvidia'
INFO: Constructing config from fragments: /home/jose/go/src/github.com/kata-containers/packaging/kernel/configs/fragments/x86_64/.config
/bin/sh: 1: bison: not found
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.c] Error 127
make: *** [allnoconfig] Error 2
INFO: Some CONFIG elements failed to make the final .config:
INFO: Value requested for CONFIG_NET_9P not in final .config
Value requested for CONFIG_NET_9P_VIRTIO not in final .config
Value requested for CONFIG_9P_FS not in final .config
Value requested for CONFIG_NETWORK_FILESYSTEMS not in final .config
Value requested for CONFIG_9P_FS_POSIX_ACL not in final .config
```

(...and many many more)

This command is supposed to be generating the config file. ("# Prepare (download guest kernel source, generate .config)")

I am a little confused on this, because where would I have set all these variables before-hand? When I check my existing config file that is in use, it in fact doesn't contain the variables, though I am not sure if this is an issue because from what I understand this command is supposed to generate the config file itself. Was there some step that I skipped prior to this? How can I get this command to run?